# How to change Visual Studio whitespace settings?

Tags: visual-studio, editor

I have whitespace characters showing in the Visual Studio code editor, and I'd like to remove them.

Answer (score 52):

Ajryan is correct but depending on your profile this menu item may be obscured.  The keyboard shortcut should still work though.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Answer (score 30):

You need to turn off showing whitespace characters. Menu: Edit > Advanced > View White Space.

Comment: The color of visible white space can be changed at `Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts And Colors->Display items: Visible White Space` on VS2017.

Answer (score 8):

If it is VS2008 then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> combination to toggle.

Answer (score 2):

For `Visual Studio 2019`:

- Toggle on/off - Option 1: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
- Toggle on/off - Option 2: `Edit > Advanced > View White Space`
- Change appearance: `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Visible White Space` (near top of list, probably because it is a commonly used setting)

Comment: I could not guess the name they would use, "Visible White Space", and then could not find it in the list. "near top of list" is a valuable info - this comment is for other developers, to notice.