# How to toggle back those annoying horizontal dots and arrows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, customization

I got some funny but annoying problem. Somehow I toggled this kind of view in my VB 2010. Tried in two hours to find solution but in vain.

How can I get back ordinary look?

Now it looks like this

[image: Now it looks like this]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Visual Studio whitespace settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257752/how-to-change-visual-studio-whitespace-settings)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CTRL R then CTRL W - toggle white space