# How to show line indentation in Visual Studios 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know how to show indentation, line spacing, cariage returns in Visual Studios 2010. Is there a plugin that I can add to Visual Studios to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Visual Studio whitespace settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257752/how-to-change-visual-studio-whitespace-settings)

Answer (score 29):

Ctrl-R, Ctrl-W
    Shows or hides spaces and tab marks

Comment: Great for a fat fingers like me who meant to press Ctrl-R, Ctrl-E! Thanks!

Comment: Worked for VS2013 too. Thank you :) I spent the last 15 minutes going through the Options dialog without being able to find this setting.

Answer (score 4):

The menu option Edit/Advanced/View Whitespace (hotkey: Ctrl-R/Ctrl-W) will show spaces and tabs - I'm not sure if there's a way to get VS to show carriage returns.

Comment: A great tip if you have conflicting keybindings! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE 2022

```
"editor.guides.indentation": true
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_bracket-pair-guides

### BEFORE 2021:

**if you use VS2014 or latest:**
use indent guide plugin,  on codeplex:
http://indentguide.codeplex.com

**For VS 2013 OR old versions:**
installs Indent Guide on:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30

Comment: Apologies for bringing-up this old answer, but it seems that Indent Guide no longer supports VS2013

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010 it is `ctrl +k +d` for indentation.

And to display lines in your indentation **just go to the Tools menu**, click on `Options -> Expand Text Editor`, **select a language,**

> for example, C#

1. and click on `General` if is not selected automatically.
2. Then, in the last section of the window named “`Display`”,
3. enable the `Line Numbers checkbox`.

Answer (score -4):

Line spacing feature is not available in Visual Studio 2010. But you can use cygwin to reduce the spacing between the lines. For more help go to this page:

http://www.electronicdissonance.com/2010/01/raster-fonts-in-visual-studio-2010.html