# How do I get line ending glyphs in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, editor

Is there any way to get line ending glyphs in Visual Studio 2012?

The following screen shot (from notepad++) show what I want (the **CR LF** part):
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might want to check out this extension: [End of The Line by Rolf W. Rasmussen](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/545e56a7-98d7-47f9-9d84-4681f2903060). The current binary version displays CR and LF identifiers at the end of the line all the time, but the source version ties it into VS's "View Whitespace" menu option.

It's for Visual Studio 2013, but it's [open source](https://bitbucket.org/rolfwr/endoftheline) and should be fairly straightforward to recompile as a VS2012 compatible plugin

(You might need to change the references - the VSSDK packages on nuget can be really useful here. You'd need [VSSDK.CoreUtility](http://www.nuget.org/packages/VSSDK.CoreUtility.11/) and [VSSDK.Text](http://www.nuget.org/packages/VSSDK.Text.11/). In fact, that might be worth a PR regardless...)

Comment: Use VS 2010, so that's a no go as only VS2012 or later is supported.

Answer (score 12):

Nope, Visual Studio has **no** feature to show End of Line Markers. ([Reference](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html))

But it gives the ability to show Whitespace with (Ctrl + E + S) which is adressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257752/how-to-change-visual-studio-whitespace-settings).
If any incosistencies are included, VS should suggest to fix the document automatically.

But if you need to do actions other than that, I recommend using [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org)  as described by Hanselman [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeathToCarriageReturnsAndLinefeeds.aspx)

If you think Visual Studio should include this feature, you better vote for [this request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2381472-view-white-space-should-show-line-endings-too)

*Edit:*

By the way, VS shows glyphs for wrapped words by enabling through:

```
Tools ->  Options ->  Text Editor ->  All Languages ->  Show visual glyphs for word wrap
```

**Like:**

[image: example for glyphs]

Comment: I voted all I could for this feature. Has become more important now that Visual Studio 2012 update 2 will have git support since git (normally) handles the line-ending char(s).