# Why am i a getting little green dashes and a green box in my code in MVS 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am new to c++ and I am having a problem with Microsoft visual studio (2010). I know there are supposed to be better c++ ide's but this is the one my school has us use. So, my problem is:

There is a little green box appearing in the text of my code file. It is pretty small, but I cannot erase it. It is always there in the top corner and moves to the right of my code as I type. Additionally, when I try to make a space I get a little green dash instead. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Before this started my laptop windows key in between the ctrl and alt button got stuck and I had to turn off the computer and brute force it back into place. I am assuming it is possible that before I did that I may have inadvertently turned on something that I don't want or understand!

Thank you in advance for help. 
edit - Here is a link to a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAmdV.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have Visual Studio configured to show whitespace and some non-printable characters.

I don't have access to my VS to check how to enable/disable this option, but I am pretty sure it is under the Edit menu. A quick search yielded this StackOverflow question: [How to change Visual Studio whitespace settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257752/how-to-change-visual-studio-whitespace-settings)